# Передать аргумент в структуру в си

Tags: c

Допустим у меня есть структура, в которой есть ряд переменных с разрядностью в 1 байт (**Char**), я её использовал для определённой задачи и мне понадобилось та же структура но с другим типом данных переменных, скажем типа **int**. 
В структуре 20 переменных, а тип поменять нужно только в одном.

Могу ли я как-то передать аргумент или параметр при создании экземпляра структуры в си?

в плюсах при создании экземпляра класса вектора, я писал:

> QVector< int >

Comment: А чем вам не нравится просто обьявить две структуры?

Comment: Похоже единственный вариант "сократить" код - макрос.

Comment: А если я хочу передать в структуру тип разных своих структур, точно также как в векторе? мне нужно передать свой тип данных (typedef), это я так на пальцах про Char и Int, на самом деле мне нужно разные типы туда посылать.

Comment: `#define MY_DEF1(x,y)  typedef struct  { y field1; int field2;  } x;` как-то так.

Comment: *А если я хочу передать в структуру тип разных своих структур* а зачем? Передавайте указатель и номер типа данных. Посмотрите как реализовано то же `sprintf` и `vsprinf` там можно передавать структуры разной длинны - работайте через указатель.

Comment: В некоторых часных случаях - можно использовать `union`.

Answer (score 1):

В C это сделать невозможно. Единственное, что вы можете сделать - это поместить общие поля в начало двух структур, а те поля, которые различаются, можно поместить во вложенную структуру данных двух структур.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите не думать о том как обобщать - разобобщите типы - создайте несколько названий типов - и используйте overload - перегруженые ф-ции. Как вариант, что б сократить колличество строк, можно воспользоваться следующим макросом

```
 #define MY_DEF1(x,y) typedef struct {\
      y field1;   \
      int field2; \
      } x;
```

Если вы хотите обобщить, то как вариант - вы можете использовать union. Но вам всёравно прийдётся "разобобщать", плюс - теряете возможность "обьявить с пердзаданными значениями".

Пример

```
 struct MyArray{
    enum {
       myarr_char,
       myarr_int
       } arrayType; // Обобщаем с помощью аргумента.
    union {
       char cA[100];
       int  cI[100];  
       }  u;       
    }

 // Вынесеный кусок
 #define MY_CODE(typ,data)  \
   if (true) {     \
        data[0] = (typ)0; \
        } 

  int MyHandler(MyArray * data) {
      switch (data->arrayType) {
         case myarr_char:
             // ... разобобщаем например так                 
             MY_CODE(char,data->u.cA); // Одинаковые куски кода 
             // можно вынести в отдельный макрос                 
             break;
         case myarr_int:
             // ... разобобщаем 
             MY_CODE(int,data->u.cI);
             break;
         }
     }
 #undef MY_CODE
```

Удобство - требует "жертв". Если не хотите передавать arrayType в структуре - его так же можно передавать вторым аргументом, код при этом не сильно изменится.